# How to Add character to the beginning of each line using netbeans

Tags: netbeans, comments, gherkin

I work with gherkin feature files.

For testing reasons I want to command out some scenarios. For this I have to put a # to the beginning of every line.

I found a hint how I can do this with sed (https://linuxconfig.org/add-character-to-the-beginning-of-each-line-using-sed).

Can I do this within Netbeans, too?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a language setting for "gherkin" or are you just using netbeans as a text editor? If it is a language, you can toggle comments with ctrl+shift+c

Comment: Thank you. 
I now found a plugin that works with Neatbeans 8.2 and supports highlighting feature files so I can comment with ctrl+shift+c
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/17939/cucumber-features
Maybe it's useful for someone else